# Apple's iOS Design Resource Library -- Apple supplies wrong font?

Tags: fonts, ios, adobe-xd

I've been using [Apple's iOS Design Resource Library](https://developer.apple.com/design/resources/#ios-apps) in Adobe XD, and have [Apple's official SF font](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/) installed. The problem is that when you open the library in Adobe XD it complains that the SF font is not installed.

As you can see from the screenshot, their Resource Library asks for "SF Pro Display".

[image]

But their SF font download only provides "SF Pro" and "SF Compact".

[image]

Anyone know what's going on? I believe their XD document is using the old version of the their SF font.

How are you supposed to remedy this?

Comment: How many people voted to close without reading the second sentence?

Comment: I recently noticed that Apple has new installers for the San Francisco and New York font families: https://developer.apple.com/fonts/. The installer gave me a bunch of seemingly similar typefaces like "SF Pro" and "SF Pro Display", so it might solve your issue depending on the XD file.